# Загрузка изображений в папку на сервер и помещение информации в базу данных

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Как можно сделать загрузку изображений со страницы сайта на сервер в определённую папку, и чтобы название файла заносилось в базу данных?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Отложим в сторону всякие проверки, их вы сделаете сами и какие хотите (и файл ли это, и доступные расширения файлов, и прочее). Вам надо определиться, с каким именем будете сохранять файл, т.к. если его не переименовать, то может случиться так, что будет загружен файл с таким же именем, как у файла загруженного раньше. Это приведет к перезаписи существующего файла. Для примера, будем задавать новое имя в зависимости с текущей меткой времени Unix. Теперь к сути:

```
$path = 'path_to_dir/'; // директория для загрузки
$ext = array_pop(explode('.',$_FILES['myfile']['name'])); // расширение
$new_name = time().'.'.$ext; // новое имя с расширением
$full_path = $path.$new_name; // полный путь с новым именем и расширением

if($_FILES['myfile']['error'] == 0){
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $full_path)){
        // Если файл успешно загружен, то вносим в БД (надеюсь, что вы знаете как)
        // Можно сохранить $full_path (полный путь) или просто имя файла - $new_name
    }
}
```

P.S. Поле файла в форме для моего примера, должно иметь атрибут name="myfile". Замените на своё значение, соответственно изменив в глобальной переменной $_FILES['myfile']

Comment: По Вашему коду понять ничего не могу. Куда его вставить?

Comment: Вот [тут скачаете файлик](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-FCjMFmnZuxYTc5a002aV9COVU). Измените путь к директории и протестируйте

Comment: @Deonis - если быть дотошным - таймстампа недостаточно :P

Comment: @AlexWindHope, так точно, сэр! ))

Comment: Это безопасно? Вирусы итд не проникнут на сервер?

Answer (score 7):

-- В файле, который должен лежать в корне сайта, чтобы относительно этого файла правильно загружать в папку изображений от корня сайта.

```
function upload_file($file, $upload_dir= 'images', $allowed_types= array('image/png','image/x-png','image/jpeg','image/webp','image/gif')){

  $blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4");
  $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // В переменную $ext заносим расширение загруженного файла.
  if(in_array($ext,$blacklist )){
    return array('error' => 'Запрещено загружать исполняемые файлы');}

  $upload_dir = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$upload_dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; // Место, куда будут загружаться файлы.
  $max_filesize = 8388608; // Максимальный размер загружаемого файла в байтах (в данном случае он равен 8 Мб).
  $prefix = date('Ymd-is_');
  $filename = $file['name']; // В переменную $filename заносим точное имя файла.

  if(!is_writable($upload_dir))  // Проверяем, доступна ли на запись папка, определенная нами под загрузку файлов.
    return array('error' => 'Невозможно загрузить файл в папку "'.$upload_dir.'". Установите права доступа - 777.');

  if(!in_array($file['type'], $allowed_types))
    return array('error' => 'Данный тип файла не поддерживается.');

  if(filesize($file['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
    return array('error' => 'файл слишком большой. максимальный размер '.intval($max_filesize/(1024*1024)).'мб');

  if(!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$upload_dir.$prefix.$filename)) // Загружаем файл в указанную папку.
    return array('error' => 'При загрузке возникли ошибки. Попробуйте ещё раз.');

    return Array('filename' => $prefix.$filename);
}
```

-- Пример отправки файла

```
<form class="user-info" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="etc" value="">
  <input id="img" name="imgfile" type="file">
  <input class="sbutton" value="Запилить" type="submit"></a></td></tr>
</form>
```

-- Обработчик для формы

```
  $etc = $_POST['etc']; // Конечно нужно фильтровать пришедшие данные

  if(isset($_FILES['imgfile']) && !empty($_FILES['imgfile']['name'])){

    $result = upload_file($_FILES['imgfile']);
    $img = 'null'; // В таблице поле должно иметь значение по умолчанию null

    if(isset($result['error'])){
      $error = $result['error'];
    }else{
      $img = '"'.$result['filename'].'"';
    }
  }

  if(!isset($error)){
    $execute = mysql_query('INSERT INTO fotos ("Image","etc") Values ('.$img.',"'.$etc.'")');
    if(!$execute)
      echo 'Ошибка обращения к базе';
  }else{
    echo $error;
  }
```