# php загрузка фото в папку

Tags: php, html, css

есть обычный слайдер, фото вставляются так:

```
  <div class="swiper-slide"> <img class="zoom" src="resources/img/1.jpg" alt=""  > </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide"> <img class="zoom" src="resources/img/2.jpg" alt=""  > </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide"> <img class="zoom" src="resources/img/3.jpg" alt=""  ></div>
  <div class="swiper-slide"> <img class="zoom" src="resources/img/4.jpeg" alt="" > </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide"> <img class="zoom" src="resources/img/5.jpg" alt="" > </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide"> <img class="zoom" src="resources/img/6.jpg" alt="" > </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide"> <img class="zoom" src="resources/img/7.jpeg" alt="" > </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide"> <img class="zoom" src="resources/img/8.jpeg" alt="" > </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide"> <img class="zoom" src="resources/img/9.jpg" alt="" > </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide"> <img class="zoom" src="resources/img/10.jpeg" alt="" > </div>
```

Как сделать что через php ты заменял фотки в папке и они менялись на сайте не смотря на их имя и расширение

Comment: За вас тут никто не будет ничего писать, показывайте код, который писали, пробовали, что не получилось, ошибки если есть. Если хотите, чтобы за вас все сделали, то тогда вы, ошиблись адресом, тут вам не биржа фриланса. И оформите вопрос подобающе. А то набор буков.

Comment: https://webformyself.com/zagruzka-izobrazhenij-s-izmeneniem-razmera/

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/125464/308951

Comment: Попробуй использовать `scandir()` и циклом выводи фото.